# Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-engines

I included an engine, within an engine. 
(including the 'core' engine inside my 'api' engine)

I.e. an engine's Gemfile included another engine. When I try using rspec, I get the following error:

```
    home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-
4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `rescue in execute_if_updated': 
Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to 
updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil: #
<Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0x007fd13a2771b8 @paths=
["home/myApp/api/spec/dummy/config/routes.rb", "home/myApp/core/config/routes.rb", 
"home/myApp/api/config/routes.rb"], @route_sets=[#
<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007fd13a0dbe30>, #
<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007fd13a29e3d0>, #
<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007fd13a42c698>]> (RuntimeError)
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3):

This could be an error in a model. I had this for example in my model:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with :thing   # <= this line caused the error, it should be
  validates_with ThingValidator
end
```

Might not be the same thing, but take a look at methods being called in your model classes.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was also something model related, so the error was misleading. In my case it was the use of active_enum in a model.